# Legends in R plots

Tags: r, plot, legend

I want to split the legend on a plot into 2, so that the first 3 elements are separated from the 4th element by a gap of about 1 line height.  I initially just tried to add a line-break before the 1st element:

```
legend("topright",col=1,lty=1:3,lwd=1,legend=c("leg1","leg2","\nleg3"), bty="n")
```

but this seems to increase the gap inbetween **all** the elements (is this documented behaviour?)

I then used 2 separate legends, setting the borders to `"n"` and using `lines()` to reconstruct the borders (incidentally, is there a way to suppress only 1 border of a legend?); although this works, it does require a lot of trial and error with the values of `inset`.

The default values of `inset` in `legend()` are `c(0,0)`, but these obviously get adjusted in the initial call to `legend()`, based on the length of the text in the elements of that legend.  According to `?legend`, the value of a `legend()` call includes the

"numeric vectors of length length(legend), giving the x and y coordinates of the legend's text(s)."

Is there anyway this can be converted into suitable values for the `inset` of the 2nd call so that the elements of both legends line up?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

just specify NAs in the arguments where you want the space to be. You'll need to give all the legend arguments as vectors.

```
    set.seed(2)
    plot(0:10, rnorm(11), col = sample(c("green", "blue"), 11, replace = TRUE), 
        pch = sample(c(3, 19), 11, replace = TRUE), xlim = c(0, 12))
    legend("topright", pch = c(3, 19, NA, 3, 19), 
        col = c("green", "green", NA, "blue", "blue"), 
        legend = c("green cross", "green dot", NA, "blue cross", "blue dot"))
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to make 2 calls to `legend()` for finer control, specify `trace=TRUE` in the arguments and it returns you the x and y coordinates you need.